# How to configure Jenkins to run my test cases in parallel?

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, system-testing

I am building a test system with Jenkins with multiple slave nodes. I have multiple test cases where each of them take at more than 15 minutes to run.

I want to make the system in a way that when I start tests Jenkins running each test case in a node which is free and at the end collects and summarizes the test results.

I have opened a Jenkins job which is general test-case job and it is parametrized where the parameter is the "test name". But I see that Jenkins is executing the jobs sequentially.

How can I configure Jenkins to run builds for the same job (with different parameters) in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple syntax for parallel:

```
pipeline {
stages {
    stage('Run Tests In Parallel') {
        parallel {
            stage('Projects Test 1') {
                agent {
                    node { label "your jenkins label" }
                }
                steps{
                   script {
                        your test 1
                   }
                }
                post{
                    always {
                        script {
                            echo ' always'                                
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            stage('Projects Test 2') {
                agent {
                    node { label "your jenkins label" }
                }
                steps{
                   script {
                        your test 2
                   }
                }
                post{
                    always {
                        script {                                
                            echo ' always'                             

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use parallel stages in jenkins which runs parallely. also use agent any at each stage so it will use any free node.

Check [Parallel Stages](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/) document for more info

Comment: I have seen this. It indeed makes builds parallel. I'm trying to find out how to generate the script automatically from the list of tests I have. I'm trying to avoid the situation where I need to add a new test in two places (one in the code, the other in Jenkins).

Comment: I have not used this myself yet, but this plugin looks promising: https://plugins.jenkins.io/parallel-test-executor/